# Increment versionCode and versionName from gardle.build(app) for any productVariant

Tags: android, build.gradle, fastlane, cicd, appcenter

This is the code of gradle.build(app) right now :

```
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.moveeasy.yourbrokerage"
      multiDexEnabled true
      minSdkVersion 22
      targetSdkVersion 30
      versionCode 25
      versionName "1.19.0"
    }
    productFlavors {
        moveeasy {
            //Updated on 21-7-2021[8 and 1.6]
            applicationId "com.moveeasy.yourbrokerage"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 17
            versionName "1.15"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```

My fastlane code is as below :

```
           android_set_version_code(
               version_code: versionCode,
               gradle_file: "app/build.gradle"
           )

           android_set_version_name(
               version_name: versionName,
               gradle_file: "app/build.gradle"
           )
```

So, now problem is this code is increases the code and name from `defaultConfig` only. I want to increase it from `productVariant/moveeasy`. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the fastlane code to increment versionCode:

```
lane :incrementVersion do
      path = '../app/build.gradle'
      vc = /versionCode\s+(\d+)/ 
      vn = /versionName\s+\"(\d+.\d+.\d+)\"/ 

      # Reading build.gradle file to get versionName and versionCode
      gradleFile = File.read(path)
      versionCode = gradleFile[vc, 1].to_i
      gradleFile[vc, 1] = (versionCode + 1).to_s

      newGradleFile = File.new(path, 'w')
      newGradleFile.write(gradleFile)
      newGradleFile.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

will there another way your can change version and version code via manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="org.test"
    android:versionCode="115"
    android:versionName="11.33">
```

Comment: I want to code for the Fastlane file. From where I can update the version code for any variant

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).